# C++ Linked List gives Segmentation fault when removing nodes with duplicate values

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, segmentation-fault

For a sorted linked list, say `1->1->1->1->2->2->3->3->4->4->4`, I want to remove all the duplicates resulting in the linked list to have every node with a unique value (i.e. the above linked list should become `1->2->3->4->`.)

```
ListNode* deleteDuplicates(ListNode* A)
{
    ListNode *ptr = A, *nextt;

    if (A == NULL) 
        return A;

    if (A->next == NULL)
        return A;

    while (1)
    {
        if ((ptr == NULL) || (ptr->next == NULL))
            break;

        nextt = ptr->next;

        while ((ptr->val == nextt->val) && (nextt != NULL))
            nextt = nextt->next;

        ptr->next = nextt;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    return A;
}
```

My algorithm is:

1. A pointer `ptr` is initially pointed to the head of the linked list. Another Pointer '`nextt` points to the next node from the head. (`ptr->next`).
2. While the value of `nextt` remains the same as `ptr`, the `nextt` pointer is traversed forward until the value is different or `nextt` reaches the end of the list.

However, on running the code, I receive a segmentation fault.

When we reach the end of the list, the inner while loop causes `nextt` to 
become `NULL`. Is this the place where the error is?

Simulating a different input on paper doesn't help either. I'm not sure where the error is.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your condition

`while((ptr->val==nextt->val) && (nextt!=NULL))`

dereferences `nextt` in order to access `nextt->val`. When `nextt` is NULL, This is an access violation.

Change your loop condition to:

`while ((next != NULL) && (ptr->val == nextt->val))`

so that if `next == NULL`, then the condition will short-circuit and evaluate to false.

Comment: Yes. That explains it. Thanks a lot. :-)